# How to save and retrieve data in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

```cs
//create post action method
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ProductType productType)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.ProductTypes.Add(productType);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    
    return View(productType);
}
```

In this case it's doesn't show any error but it does not work.. Where is the mistake?

Comment: We need more information, i.e., how `ProductType` looks like, how the view looks like etc. There are so many things that could go wrong. For example, you might forgot to put validation summary on the view and the ModelState is not valid (maybe you forgot to put the product type id in a hidden field and it's required?). It will basically return to the same view without displaying errors. That might be what you're seeing. Again I don't know how many times I've said in Stack Overflow - do not expose your domain model to the view. Instead, create a view model that only contains what the view needs

Answer (score 0):

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //create post action method
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("column1,column2,column3,..")] ProductType productType)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Add(productType);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(productType);
    }
```

You need to remove ProductTypes. before .Add(productType); function.
The correct statement is -
_db.Add(productType);

Also, You can bind the column

Would you try this code again. Hope it will work. If doesn't work, can you share the view code pls. I would like to solve your problem.

Comment: public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("column1,column2,column3,..")] ProductType productType)

You can Bind the column

Comment: Apply the above updated code, Build the project. If doesn't work again. Then I think there was another issue.

Comment: Yes I also think it has another issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Can you please check the > Views > _ViewImports.cshtml

If the above @addTagHelper doesn't exist please add this...